# Why are more American movies are coming out in foreign countries first?

Tags: film-industry, distribution

While chatting about the movie Jupiter Ascending in the chat room, I learned that the movie is [apparently already out in many European countries](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1617661/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9), whereas the movie comes out today, 6 February 2015, in the United States. Over the last several years I've noticed that this trend seems to be increasing:

- [The Amazing Spider-Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) had its premiere in Tokyo, Japan on 30
  June 2012, where as the American release wasn't until 3 July 2012.
  [Its sequel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1872181/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) hit UK theaters nearly an entire month before it hit
  US theaters.
- While [Kick-Ass](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1250777/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) had a premiere at Sundance, it went wide in the
  UK on 26 March 2010, and didn't go wide in the US until 16 April. [Its sequel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1650554/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) had a much smaller window for releasing early in the UK before the US, but still, it hit the UK before it hit the
  US.
- [Transformers: Age of Extinction](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2109248/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) hit Asian markets about 2 to 3
  days before it premiered in the US.
- [X-Men: Days of Future Past](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1877832/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9) hit the UK a couple weeks before it
  hit the US.
- [The Hunger Games: Catching Fire](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951264/?ref_=fn_al_tt_5), a sequel, came out in Europe
  before the US, as did the [third film](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1951265/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9).
- [Jack Ryan: Shadow Recruit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1205537/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ql_9), a movie based on a Tom Clancy
  character (and a very American franchise to begin with) came out in
  Europe and some Asian/Pacific regions before the US.

My question is: **Why does it seem like more and more movies produced in the US hit foreign markets before they hit the US market?** I'm not asking out of some misplaced sense of patriotism or American zealotry, but movies produced by US studios used to take quite a bit longer to hit foreign theaters after making it to US theaters. Are distribution methods simply faster? Is there a marketing reason? What's the deal?

Comment: Yep, sure enough. Those with closing powers please vote to close as a duplicate.